# Bootstrap not working properly when clicking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When the screen is small the bootstrap bottom doesn´t work properly.

Here you can access to my web: http://safelinking.net/pz1Y9fP

As you can see when i click on the bottom,  the menu doesn´t appear. it mustn´t appear at first, and when you click the bottom must appear and disappear.

what´s wrong?

Comment: I'm confused, where am I supposed to be clicking? Can you include some screenshots?

Comment: [link]( http://safelinking.net/qNciM6i ) here is the screenshot. as you can see the menu is always opened althoght i click the botton.

Comment: REsolve the problem. THe problem was that i have comment a few lines in template.css that are necessary.